# Get EMEI or phone ID from NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

How can I get the phone EMEI or the phone ID from ndk support.

Is there any other unique information from the device that I can use?

Comment: [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/0AiE_ohuUjM) details a JNI way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [JNI](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html) (which provides the bridge between NDK and SDK).

In this way, you can get device's IMEI using Java APIs ([`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) is available there).

Comment: I saw this possibility, but I'm migrating a legacy code and it's difficult to pass the JNIEnv to that part of code. There is no c/c++ pure code solution? thanks for the answer.

Comment: I understand. But no, there is no way to do it directly in C/C++ to my knowledge. Your welcome.

Comment: Pass the IMEI as an extra string parameter from Java, store it in a global/static on the C side.